# How to properly get the information about all registrations in a specific congress?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a registration form for a user to register in a congress.

For example, if the user John is doing a registration in a congress and a registration with 2 participants (him and his colleague Jake) and John is registering him in ticket type `tt1` and Jake in the ticket type `tt2` in the database is inserted an entry in the Registrations table to store which user did the registration and in which congress. Then, it is also inserted in the participants table an entry for each registered participant by the user that did the registration (main_participant). So the tables stay like:

**`registrations` table**

```
id | status | congress_id | main_participant_id
---+--------+-------------+--------------------
7  | C      | 1           | 1
```

**`participants` table**

```
id | registration_id | ticket_type_id | name | surname
---+-----------------+----------------+------+--------
12 | 7               | 1              | John | W
13 | 7               | 2              | Jake | Y
```

Now I have a `ParticipantController` that has the `index` method, that gets the info of a specific `Congress`:

```
class ParticipantController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        $congress = Congress::find($id);
        return view('participants.index')->with('congress', $congress);
    }
}
```

In this `participants.index` view I want to list in a table the registrations deails:

1. all users that did a registration in this specific congress;
2. the quantity of tickets that they acquired;
3. the ticket types; and
4. the status of the registration (Complete, Incomplete).

So, is it possible to have a table in the following image?

[image]

What is necessary to properly get this information? I'm not understanding how to get this. Both tables in the image above are the same, the only difference is:

- the first part of the image is when `all_participant` is `1` in the `congresses` table, which means in the congress registration form was necessary to collect info (name and surname) of each participant, so the user that did the registration needed to introduce the name and surname of each participant. Then, the name and surname of each participant should appear in the modal, as in the image.
- in the case when `all_participant` is `0` in the `congresses` table the name and surname of each participant are blank (`''`). That's because in the registration form was not necessary to collect info of each participant.

Related to the **Ticket type(s)** column in the table: a user can do a registration with multiple participants. For example, John can select 2 ticekts, one of the ticket type `tt1` and other of the ticket type `tt2`. If the registration includes 1 or more ticket types it should appear in the **Ticket type(s)** column the ticket types associated with that specific registratation, as in the image above for the first registration (for the user John W).

With this code in the `ParticipantController`:

```
 $allRegistrations = $congress->registrations()->get();
```

And then in the view:

```
@foreach ($allRegistrations as $r)
    {{ $r }}
@endforeach
```

I got:

```
{"id":10,"status":"C","congress_id":1,"main_participant_id":1}
```

The status can be gotten like `{{ $r->status }}`. But, how to get the other necessary info that is in the image? The quantity, ticket types and the name of the user that did the registration? And the info in the modal: the name and surname of each participant, or show `""` if `all_participant` is `0`, and also the ticket type associated to each participant.

To show all registrations and the necessary info as in the image, I don't know if the database structure I have allows to get that information properly. For now, the database looks like this:

[image]

**Laravel models:**

```
// Congress model
class Congress extends Model
{ 
    // A conference has one creator
    public function creator(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'congress_id');
    }
}

// User model
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function congresses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Congress', 'user_id');
    }

    // A user can register in many conferences
    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration','main_participant_id');
    }
}

// Registration model
class Registration extends Model
{
    // a registration has one user that do the registration
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // a registration can have many participants
    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}

// Participant Model
class Participant extends Model
{
    // a participant belongs to a registration
    public function registration(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
}

// Ticket Type model
class TicketType extends Model
{
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'ticket_type_questions')->withPivot(['required']);;
    }
}

// Question model
class Question extends Model
{
    public function ticket_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TicketType', 'ticket_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }
}

// Answer model
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Question');
    }
    public function participant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Participant');
    }
}

// TicketTypeQuestion model
class TicketTypeQuestion extends Model
{
}
```

Finally, a ticket type may have custom questions associated to it. For example, in the image below both ticket types `tt1` and `tt2` have the custom question *"Whats your phone?"* associated to them. In that case, the answers to these questions, answered by the use that did the registration, should appear in the modal when the user clicks in the `+` to see the details. How to get these answers? In this image examples the phone of the participant 1 is `002..` and the phone of the participant 2 is `003..`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer was updated based on information provided in the comments.**

First, you have to fix the relation between `Registration` and `User` class. It is using the [default column naming](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse), but your schema uses a different one:

```
class Registration extends Model
{

    // ...

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'main_participant_id');
    }

    // ...

}
```

If you have access to do that, I would suggest you to change that column's name to something more clear. The current name takes one to assume it references the `participants` table.

With that relation fixed, you are now able to get the main participant by calling its magic property. This will return a `User` model instance:

```
$registration->customer;
```

Additionaly, you have to add a relation between participants and ticket types to your `Participant` class:

```
class Participant extends Model
{

    // ...

    public function ticketType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TicketType');
    }

    // ...

}
```

This relation will allow you to get the ticket type details, including its name, from any participant model instance.

Then, on the view, you should be able to do the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach ($congress->registrations as $registration)

            <!-- User that did the registration -->
            <td>{{ $registration->customer->name }}</td>

            <!-- Email.
                 Although, I don't see an email field in your DB schema -->
            <td>{{ $registration->customer->email }}</td>

            <!-- Ticket types -->
            <td>
                {{
                    $registration->participants
                        ->map(function ($participant) {
                            return $participant->ticket_type->name;
                        })
                        ->implode(', ')
                }}
            </td>

            <!-- Quantity -->
            <td>{{ $registration->participants->count() }}</td>

            <!-- Status -->
            <td>{{ $registration->status === 'C' ? 'Confirmed' : 'Waiting' }}</td>

            <!-- Date. Considering a Carbon instance.
                 Although, I don't see a created_at field in your DB schema -->
            <td>{{ $registration->created_at->format('m/d/y') }}</td>

        @endforeach
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I used a "trick" to get all the types within a single method chain. That's possible because Eloquent results, except for when a single instance is returned and other special cases, are usually `Collection`s. You can learn more about Eloquent collections and the available methods on the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods). Also, notice my comments above on missing fields.

Finally, for the second view, you can iterate through all participants of a specific registration:

```
<!-- User that did the registration -->
<dl>
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>{{ $registration->customer->name }}</dd>
    <dt>Email</dt>
    <dd>{{ $registration->customer->email }}</dd>
</dl>

@foreach ($registration->participants as $participant)

    <!-- Participant N -->
    <dl>
        <dt>Name</dt>
        <dd>{{ $participant->name }}</dd>
        <dt>Surname</dt>
        <dd>{{ $participant->surname }}</dd>
        <dt>Ticket Type</dt>
        <dd>tt{{ $participant->ticket_type_id }}</dd>
    </dl>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, in the ParticipantController the index() method remains as it is in the question? Like: class ParticipantController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id){
        $congress = Congress::find($id);

        $allRegistrations = $congress->registrations()->get();

        return view('participants.index')->with('congress', $congress);
    }
}
?

Comment: With "                            <td>{{$registration->mainParticipant->name}}e</td>
" it appears "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'participants.participant_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `participants` where `participants`.`participant_id` = 1 and `participants`.`participant_id` is not null limit 1) ".

Comment: @joW My bad. The right relation is the following: `return $this->hasOne('App\Participant', 'id', 'main_participant_id');`. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks,  but now appears "Trying to get property of non-object" in " <td><?php echo e($registration->mainParticipant->name); ?>e</td>".

Comment: Do you have a record in your `participants` table for `id = 1`? If you don't, you may have an inconsistency in your DB.

Comment: BTW, I'm considering `registrations.main_participant_id` references `participants.id`. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Thanks, the registrations table has the column main_participant_id, that is the id of the user in the users table tha tdid the registration.

Comment: It seems that is working now the name and surname, in the ticket types appears "tt1, tt2" but the name of the ticket types in the database are "ticketype1" and "ticketype2". A conference can have many ticket types and a ticket type can have any name, the conference creator can give any name to the ticket type when he creates a conference and the respective ticket types.

Comment: @joW I'm sorry, but it seems you should spend some time reading the Eloquent docs, specially about relationships. From now on, it's just a matter of "linking" your models through relations, as you did for others. To get the ticket name, for instance, you should be able to do something like `$participant->ticket_type->name` if you have the proper relation in place. The main goal of SO is to help with specific problems. If we keep discussing the way we're doing, I'll end up telling you every step to complete your code. Enjoy the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)!

Comment: Thanks, my doubt in that part is how to get all ticket types because a user can do a registration and in that registration associate  participants with different ticket types. And in the table should appear all ticket types associated to the registration not only one. So using only something like "$participant->ticket_type->name" will not show all ticket types associated to a specific registration.

Comment: This "                            <td>{{$registration->participant->ticket_type->name}}</td>
" shows "Property [ticket_type] does not exist on this collection instance.".

Comment: But also in the other part get only one ticket type name it appers an error. The  "$participant->ticket_type_id" shows the correct with but "$participant->ticket_type->name" shows the error "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171179/discussion-between-gustavo-straube-and-jow).

Comment: In the question there is this part "...a ticket type may have custom questions associated to it. For example, in the image both ticket types tt1 and tt2 have the custom question "Whats your phone?" associated to them. In that case, the answers to these questions, answered by the use that did the registration, should appear in the modal when the user clicks in the + to see the details..."

Im with some doubts how to get that answers. What is necessary to get the answers is also have a relationship,  a 1 to many relationship between Participant and Answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get all the data as follows:

```
class ParticipantController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Congress $congress) {
        return view('participants.index')->with('congress', $congress->load('registrations.participants');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
    <th>User that did the registration</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>

@foreach($congress->registrations as $registration)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $registration->participants->where('ticket_type_id', $congress->main_participant_id)->first()->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $registration->participants->count() }}</td>
        <td>{{ $registration->status === 'C' ? 'Complete' : 'Incomplete' }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Some of this view logic probably belongs in the model or decorator.

Comment: Thanks, only the user that did the registration name is not appearing, it appears like "[]" Do you know why? The main_participant_id is a column of the registrations table, the main_participant_id for example "1" is the id of the user "1" in the users table, which means that was the user with id "1" that did the registartion.

Comment: For example if the user John  that has id "1" in the users table did a registration in the congress in he registrations table the main_participant_id will be "1" because is the id of the user that did the registration.

Comment: Ok then it becomes easier, just add a relationship for it and use that.

Comment: Thanks but it appears "Trying to get property of non-object". Maybe is because this "$congress->main_participant_id" appears as null.

Comment: yeah if main_participant_id is null the lookup will fail, the code assumes that there is one. You can add more checks around using conditionals, or enforce it using validation in previous steps.

Comment: Thanks, but the main_participant_id in the database is not null. Maybe the issue is that the main_participant_id is not a column of the congresses table is a column of the registrations table.

Comment: The `customer()` relationship on your `Registration` model is wrong. You may want to use something along the lines: `public function customer() { return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'main_participant_id', 'id'); }`

Comment: Thanks, but it appears "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: Do you know on which line it occurs? Are you sure your test data is valid and looks like you described above?

Comment: @joW you get null, cause you don't have `$congress->main_participant_id` in your db, so either add this one, or try to access via other models like, for example `->registrations...` where you have this one...

Comment: The error is in " <td>{{ $registration->participants->where('ticket_type_id', $congress->main_participant_id)
                            ->first()->name }}</td>".

Comment: @joW so what is the error in detail? Btw you should not place query logic in views, better move it to controller and in view present only result...

Comment: It appears "Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Users/johnw/projects/proj/resources/views/registrations/index.blade.php)" in " <td><?php echo e($registration->participants->where('ticket_type_id', $congress->main_participant_id)
                            ->first()->name); ?></td>".

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about MySQL query. This is query to get the information about all registrations in a specific congress?

```
SELECT * FROM `Registrations` r
INNER JOIN Participants p on p.registration_id = r.id
WHERE congress_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is using larave and eloquent.